# Can't boot from Live CD to fix Grub problem

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, release-upgrade

I have a dual boot of Win7 and Ubuntu on my HP laptop. I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 today and on restart I got a different black Grub screen instead of the usual purple one. (GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.1) Each boot option only returns error messages.

> error: no such partition.

I read on some other posts that I should make a live CD and boot there to use the boot repair tool but my laptop wont boot from the disk.

I have changed the BIOS setting so that boot from disk is first and also tried telling it to boot from CD in the Startup Menu. Each time I restart however the CD drive starts to run and then the Grub menu appears.

The CD runs fine on another laptop and is the correct 64bit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the grub menu appears means that your notebook can't boot from this CD. 
There are some reasons to be taken into account.

1.) Clean the Lens of your CD/DVD-Reader.

2.) Try to boot from other bootable CD's/DVD's. Do they all fail?

3.) Double-Check the system requirements for the specific Ubuntu-Version you made the CD from. 12.04 expects a PAE capable CPU. It won't boot if your CPU doesn't support this feature. Try to use an older image.

I have encountered a very similar problem on an Arima notebook. Finally it was the the built-in DVD-Writer, which had become old, lazy, and little dusty. Cleaning the lense with a cleaning liquid did the job and made the system boot form CD after a dozen of system restarts - all of them coming up with grub from the hdd.

P.S.: If all fails, you could boot from a memory stick.

Comment: I cleaned the lens and it booted on the next attempt. Eventually managed to get bootrepair to work, all is back to normal now. Thanks very much!